# Open Cmd with a jar file and execute the program

Tags: java, jar

Hi I want to open mi cmd program from the jar file of NetBeans

We will call the program "Super_Program". The program should be run on the cmd but I have a jar file so how can I open cmd from a code in the jar file that also executes it

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure whether you don't actually want to start your net beans from cmd, i.e. the other way around. Please confirm or deny, with reason.

Comment: You can do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("");`. Or if you want to run multiple times you can do `Runtime rn = Runtime.getRuntime(); rn.exec("");` ...(and so on). The runtime class is present in the `java.awt` package.

Answer (score 1):

Use **ProcessBuilder** to execute commands on the OS. Please see this example on [How to execute a shell command from Java](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/).